# NSURLConnection started then app goes to background, does it continue when app resumes?

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

If I start an NSURLConnection, before it is finished, I put the app to background, then resume it, does the connection continues from where it is left, or is it stopped?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have used synchronous request in my appln. It resumes from where it left.